# Where can i find the PKCS11 unmanaged library for the cherry SmartTerminal ST-1144

Tags: c#, .net, pkcs#11, pkcs11interop

I want to use the cherry SmartTerminal ST-1144 in order to finally sign pdf documents with certificates from a smartcard.
I do use the .net [PKCS11Interop](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop). In the following code i need to provide the unmanaged PKCS11 library for the Cherry SmartTerminal ST-1144:

```
            using (IPkcs11Library pkcs11Library = factories.Pkcs11LibraryFactory.LoadPkcs11Library(factories, pkcs11LibraryPath, AppType.MultiThreaded))
```

My problem is that i don't know where i can find this unmanaged library. I've installed the provided software from cherry, but none of the listed dll's could be loaded.
[image]
The error is always

> Net.Pkcs11Interop.Common.UnmanagedException: 'Unable to load library. Error code: 0x0000007E. Error detail: The specified module could not be found'

I guess those are not compatible libraries.
I also tried to contact the support from cherry but had no success so far.

Any idea

- If this cherry smartterminal is compatible with IPkcs11Library?
- What is the name of the dll which can be used as pkcs11LibraryPath?

Comment: Try to search though newly installed files for text `C_GetFunctionList` - it will be PKCS#11 module.

Comment: `system32` and `SysWOW64` folders path can be omitted.

Comment: I did search for this text in the installation directory but without any success.

Comment: Repeat search through `system32` and `SysWOW64` folders.

Comment: No luck either. The search does actually work. I've tested it with opensc_pkcs11.dll which is found based on this search, but this is not compatible with my cherry reader.  Could it be that this cherry smartcard terminal doesn't support PKCS11 at all?

Comment: Jaroslav says all needed words in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PKCS#11 library is not driver for card reader (in your case Cherry SmartTerminal ST-1144). PKCS#11 library is driver for the card. So I highly doubt such library is installed as a part of package provided by Cherry. It should be installed as part of software you got with your smartcard.